# Copy one file from subdirectory

Tags: bash, copy, wildcard, subdirectory

Dear scripting experts, 
as  a newcomer to scripting, I would appreciate your help very much.
I have a simple task in mind:
I have a set of directories dir1 dirxy dir...
There are some files in each directory but I want to copy just one of them, lets say a file beginning A...

Searching this page I found a script for listing thru subdirectories:

```
for i in *
do                 # Line breaks are important
    if [ -d $i ]   # Spaces are important
        then
            "do some task"
    fi
done
```

Do some task is a problem...
I want to copy a file stating with A* to another directory and rename it to B_nameofparentdirectory

Thank you very much
Petr

Answer (score 1):

You can have a glob match only directories by ending it with a slash, so you can write your script

```
for i in */; do
  "do some task"
done
```

Within each directory you can then use the `break` statement to make the inner loop only process the first file:

```
for i in */; do
  for f in "${i}"A*; do
    cp "$f" "$dest/B_$dest"
    break
  done
done
```

This will cause the loop to continue processing each outer directory, but within each directory only the first file named A* will be processed.

That said, you can accomplish this a bit more directly with a `find` command:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'A*' -execdir cp {} "$dest/B_$dest" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding implementation similar to other answer using find

```
for file in $(find . -name "A*" -type f)
do      
    cp ${file} ${destDir}/B_${destDir}
    break
done
```

You can use find for this to list all files beginning with A in the current directory & its subdirectories.

```
find . -name "A*" -type f
```

Comment: You probably just want `.` instead of `pwd`. Barring that, you may want `$PWD`.

Comment: @kojiro Yes a `.` would suffice and normally I use that but is ``pwd`` not recommended. Thanks.

Comment: `pwd` in backticks would run `pwd` in a subshell, so it's a pretty costly operation to get a value the shell already knows as both $PWD and `.`. I would not recommend it in this case.